# EPiServer XForm - Attaching file to an email

Tags: file, email, upload, xforms, episerver

I have been trying to follow this blog http://world.episerver.com/Blogs/Anders-Hattestad/Dates/2013/1/Upload-within-Xform/

The form upload works, however the file does not appear in the email, but is uploaded onto the server, so its doing something.

The instructions I have are...

Just attach to the

```
BeforeSubmitPostedData event 
Check if ((e.FormData.ChannelOptions & ChannelOptions.Email) != ChannelOptions.Email) is true
```

then send the custom mail and remove the send mail option

```
e.FormData.ChannelOptions &= ~ChannelOptions.Email;
```

If anyone could simplify this for me, would be appreciated...

Many Thanks.

Marc.

Answer (score 2):

in Application_Start in your global.asax you need to attach to the XFormControl.ControlSetup Event

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   XFormControl.ControlSetup += new EventHandler(XForm_ControlSetup);
}
```

Then in your XForm_ControlSetup method, attach to the relevant event

```
public void XForm_ControlSetup(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XFormControl control = (XFormControl)sender;

    control.BeforeSubmitPostedData += new SaveFormDataEventHandler(XForm_BeforeSubmitPostedData);
}
```

And in your XForm_BeforeSubmitPostedData method

```
public void XForm_BeforeSubmitPostedData(object sender, SaveFormDataEventArgs e)
{
    // Untested
    if ((e.FormData.ChannelOptions & ChannelOptions.Email) != ChannelOptions.Email)
    {
         // Send custom mail here

         // Remove the send mail option
         e.FormData.ChannelOptions &= ~ChannelOptions.Email;
    }
    // End untested :)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply!
I don't have a Control Setup in my Form.ascx.cs file at the moment, shall I just add one??
Also, adding the top line crashes the site...

Will give the BeforeSumbitPostedData a go, as that line does exist..

Many Thanks.

Comment: ControlSetup is a static event on the XFormControl class. http://sdk.episerver.com/library/cms6/html/E_EPiServer_XForms_WebControls_XFormControl_ControlSetup.htm

What do you mean by adding the top line crashes the site?